# OSX: Moving a file from Trash to its previous location programmatically

Tags: macos, nsfilemanager, recycle-bin

OSX: Is there a way to restore a file from trash programmatically? I tried using NSFileManager but it results in error

```
NSFileManager* fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError* err;
[fm copyItemAtPath:@"/Users/xyz/.Trash/abc.txt" toPath:@"/Users/xyz/Desktop/" error:&err];
NSLog(@"err:%@",err)
```

Error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "“abc.txt” couldn’t be copied to “Desktop” because an item with the same name already exists." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/xyz/.Trash/abc.txt, NSUserStringVariant=(
Copy), NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/xyz/Desktop, NSFilePath=/Users/xyz/.Trash/abc.txt, NSUnderlyingError=0x610000041560 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 "File exists"}}
```

Comment: Take a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707618/put-back-items-from-trash-programmatically and http://superuser.com/questions/116703/move-file-to-trash-on-snow-leopard-from-terminal

Answer (score 0):

It appears that providing a different name to the destination path solves the problem

```
[fm copyItemAtPath:@"/Users/xyz/.Trash/abc.txt" toPath:@"/Users/xyz/Desktop/xyz.txt" error:&err];
```